# VSCode keyboard shortcut for specific task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

This keyboard shortcut:

```
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Hello1"
  },
]
```

opens a menu of all tasks instead of immediately running the Hello1 task

[image]

tasks.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Hello1",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo Hello1",
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
      "label": "Hello2",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "echo Hello2",
      "problemMatcher": []
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this, but try enabling `Tasks> Quick Open: Skip` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Mark thanks, no luck though. Also experimented with `Tasks> Quick Open: Detail`

Comment: I copied your code into my keybindings.json and tasks.json and I don't get that Run Task panel listing of tasks...  Reload vscode?

Comment: Restart - no luck. On latest VSCode 1.42.1. Cleared `settings.json`.

Comment: I'm still getting this same problem, even though the issue @ChangReily mentioned claims it has been fixed. Do you still have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is reported to VS Code by another guy.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/90344

1.43.0 already fixed it.