# There is any way to run task directy, with skipping task prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Like in title, is there any way to run task with skipping task prompt?

My `keybindings.json`, and `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "key": "f4",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "echo"
}
```

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "echo",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo Hello",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

And everything works fine, except when I click `f4` the prompt `Select the task to run` appear where I have to click `Enter` to run task. I want to run task directly skipping the prompt step.

I know why this happens because [runTask](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands):

> workbench.action.tasks.runTask - Run Task
>
> args - Filters the tasks shown in the Quick Pick

Is there any hack?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. 1) Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. 2) Do you have _multiple_ tasks with "echo" in their label? But for me, even when I also make an "echo2" task, f4 will just run "echo" and not prompt to pick "echo" or "echo2".

Comment: if you're on a _really really_ old version of VS Code, this might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60572793/11107541

Comment: @starball thanks for comment, it helps me find mistake.

Comment: given that you found the problem has to do with a mistake that has no way for anyone else to know except for you, I suggest that this question be closed as "not reproducible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File `keybindings.json` created in `.vscode` folder in your project directory will not work.

Make sure you edit right `keybindings.json` file, which is located at `C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\keybindings.json`.